# bash: how to merge files containing digits at certain position

Tags: regex, bash, cat

I want to merge all files, which have one or two digits at certain position. Basically I want to match numbers from 1-22.

I write in bash:

```
cat chr[0-9][0-9]{0,}_from6_new_mono.txt >all_autosomes_from6_new_mono.txt
```

I get this error:

```
cat: chr[0-9][0-9]0_from6_new_mono.txt: No such file or directory
```

However file names look like this:

```
chr22_from6_new_mono.txt
```

or

```
chr1_from6_new_mono.txt
```

Could somebody pls advice me where could be problem? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash` you can use curly brace expansion to denote a number range:

```
cat chr{1..22}_from_6_new_mono.txt >merged
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure, you use the brace-expansion correctly?

look at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion for more informations